# start and stop a background video on navigation link clicks with jQuery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I click "home" nav link, background video starts then stops after a few seconds. 
i click "about" the video starts up again where it stopped last and plays for a few seconds. 
and continue this through the nav bar clicks.

This is what i've come up with so far. I am ignoring the making it a background video right now and just trying to control the start and stop with a simple button. the video will not start on button click. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>




<a href="#" onclick="play1()"> clickme </a>


<video width="800" height="600" 
       name="Video Name" src="2160p.mov"></video>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"   integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
function play1(){
document.getElementById("2160p.mov").currentTime=3;
document.getElementById("2160p.mov").play();
setTimeout(3000,"stopvideo()")
}
function stopvideo(){
document.getELementById("2160p.mov").stop();

}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure `document.getElementById("2160p.mov")` actually get the video player? as far as I know, it works when you get the ID of the element. Put an ID on that video player and use the ID instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

- Your `video` tag has no `id` set but you are calling `document.getElementById("2160p.mov")` which obviously does not works. You can fix this by first adding any id to `video`.
- `setTimeout(3000,"stopvideo()")` syntax is incorrect. Correct way is `setTimeout(stopvideo, 3000)`. For more info: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
- Also, [`HTML Video element (<video>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) does not have and stop() event. Instead you can use `pause()` to acheive desired behvaiour. There are many other [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Events) which you can check out which might help.

So, update your HTML like:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="800" height="600" name="Video Name" src="2160p.mov"></video>
```

and then update your js code like:

```
function play1() {
   document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime = 3;
   document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
   setTimeout(stopvideo, 3000);
}

function stopvideo() {
   document.getElementById("myVideo").pause();
}
```

**DEMO:**

```js
function play1() {
   document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime = 3;
   document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
   setTimeout(stopvideo, 3000);
}

function stopvideo() {
   document.getElementById("myVideo").pause();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="play1()">Play</a><br/>
<video id="myVideo" width="400" height="300" name="Video Name" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls></video>
```

Comment: i clicked up on it but i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: will do. 1 minute and i can make it accepted. question. the video plays completely through. it doesn't stop after three seconds. any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the code and also added a working demo. Please check them out.